# Large Size XML(6 GB) to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, xml-parsing

I want to extract some attributes from an XML file, there is stack overflow dump file Users.xml and it's size is 6.5 GB.

The code i am using to perform this job is using a lot of ram, about 32 GB.

'''

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import pandas as pd
    tree = ET.parse('Users.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    dfcols = ['row_id', 'reputation', 'creation_date','diaplay_name','lastaccessdate','location','views','upvotes','downvotes','AboutMe','WebsiteUrl','ProfileImageUrl']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)
    
    for node in root:
        row_id = node.attrib.get('row Id')
        reputation = node.attrib.get('Reputation')
        creation_date = node.attrib.get('CreationDate')  
        diaplay_name = node.attrib.get('DisplayName')
        lastaccessdate = node.attrib.get('LastAccessDate')
        location = node.attrib.get('Location')
        views = node.attrib.get('Views')
        upvotes = node.attrib.get('UpVotes')
        downvotes = node.attrib.get('DownVotes')
        abtme    =node.attrib.get('AboutMe')
        WebsiteUrl=node.attrib.get('WebsiteUrl')
        ProfileImageUrl=node.attrib.get('ProfileImageUrl')
        df_xml = df_xml.append(
                pd.Series([row_id, reputation, creation_date,diaplay_name,lastaccessdate,location,views,upvotes,downvotes,abtme,WebsiteUrl,ProfileImageUrl], index=dfcols),
                ignore_index=True)
```

'''

I'd like to know if there is a way i can process the xml file in chunks.
I've read read similar other questions but none of them have arrived at a concrete solution.

Comment: When does it crash with a stack overflow? Upon parsing?

Comment: I suggest taking look at [xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse)

Comment: @Tarik it crashed when i was using Google Colab as the ram requirement was higher, so i am using another system. and yeah it crashed while parsing. But currently i am running this on other system and it's been running since 7 hrs on a xeon processor

Comment: @Daweo will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Use xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser(*, target=None, encoding=None)

"This class is the low-level building block of the module. It uses xml.parsers.expat for efficient, event-based parsing of XML. It can be fed XML data incrementally with the feed() method, and parsing events are translated to a push API - by invoking callbacks on the target object. If target is omitted, the standard TreeBuilder is used. If encoding 1 is given, the value overrides the encoding specified in the XML file."

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Sample code provided on the web page:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser
class MaxDepth:                     # The target object of the parser
    maxDepth = 0
    depth = 0
    def start(self, tag, attrib):   # Called for each opening tag.
        self.depth += 1
        if self.depth > self.maxDepth:
            self.maxDepth = self.depth
    def end(self, tag):             # Called for each closing tag.
        self.depth -= 1
    def data(self, data):
        pass            # We do not need to do anything with data.
    def close(self):    # Called when all data has been parsed.
        return self.maxDepth

target = MaxDepth()
parser = XMLParser(target=target)
exampleXml = """
<a>
  <b>
  </b>
  <b>
      <c>
      <d>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>"""
parser.feed(exampleXml)
parser.close()
```

You should modify the MaxDepth class to have start, end and data methods grab the data you require and store it in CSV.